# Sql Statement from PHP isnt inserting into Database but doesnt give an error

Tags: php, mysql

Thanks to this site i could manage to solve my problems, but my statement isnt going through on my database, but when i copy it and paste it directly to my database, it inserts without any problem. Here my code:

```
<?php
$ip   = "***"; //MySQL Server IP
$user = "***"; //MySQL user
$pw   = "***"; //MySQL password
$db   = "***"; //Database  
$sql_filter = "";


$con = mysqli_connect($ip, $user, $pw, $db);    
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();
}   

function register()
{
    $username = $_POST[username];
    $vorname = $_POST[vorname];
    $nachname = $_POST[nachname];
    $geschlecht = $_POST[geschlecht];
    $geburtsdate = $_POST[geburtsdatum];
    $password = $_POST[password];
    $email = $_POST[email];

    if($email!="" and $password!="" and $username!="" and $password==$_POST["password_confirm"])
    {           

        $sql_filter = "INSERT INTO `tblUser`(`UserID`, `UserName`, `Vorname`, `Nachname`, `EMail`, `Geschlecht`,`Password`) VALUES ('','$username','$vorname','$nachname','$email','$geschlecht','$password')";

        $_SESSION['filter'] = $sql_filter;
        $page_query = mysqli_query($con, $_SESSION['filter']);
        $page_nums = mysqli_num_rows($page_query);

        //header('Location: index.php');

        echo $sql_filter;
        echo $_SESSION['filter'];
    }
    else
    {
        header('Location: 404.html');
    }
}   

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    register();
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: if `UserID` is Primary key and autoincrement then no need to write when inserting into table

Comment: You should check this link to find mysql error http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: when i copy the statement with data, and execute it on the database, it inserts without any problem

Comment: Do you have autocommit disabled?

Comment: I can write you guys if this is helping or not later that day, because my school has all the ports blocked that i can access the webspace and the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is your `$con` is undefined in the function register(). So add this in the beginning of your function :

```
function register()
{
     global $con;
     ... // the rest of your function
}
```